# D3.js grouped bar chart text on bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, bar-chart

I used [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/3887051) as base  and need to have the columns (65 Years and Over, 45 to 64 Years, ....) to be text on the bars itself or with a second bunch of labels below the states on the x axis.

I guess that should be relatively easy, but I can't figure it out. if it makes it easier, I don't need the different colored bars, I added padding to each bar in one group and color them depending on the value passing a certain threshold or not.

so it should look like one of these two grouped bars in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKzsW.jpg)

[image]

Comment: did u get this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `text` elements in the same way that you're adding the bars themselves. The code would look like this.

```
state.selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
  .text(function(d, i) { return ageNames.slice()[i]; });
```

You might have to tweak the `x`/`y` positions and the rotations to align the labels properly.

Comment: it displays n number of times as n grouops in charts