# Text inside Bar of the Grouped Bar Chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I did refer this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 and made this bar Chart with some modification. Trying to add text inside the bar which is count basically. for example Upstream is 50, So 50 should be in the bar.

For that I tried, [D3.js grouped bar chart text on bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898291/d3-js-grouped-bar-chart-text-on-bars), [How to label each bar from a grouped bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829691/how-to-label-each-bar-from-a-grouped-bar-chart) but unable to do.

```js
var data = [{
    "title": "abc",
    "Upstream": 50,
    "Downstream": 15
  },
  {
    "title": "xyz",
    "Upstream": 107,
    "Downstream": 12
  }
]
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["green", "red"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "title";
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
});

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.title;
}));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
})]);

// x-axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Y-axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Number of Regulated Genes");

// Bars
var title = svg.selectAll(".title")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.title) + ",0)";
  });

title.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ages;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

// Legends which is in right side
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `<text>` after `<rect>` as shown in the snippet:

```js
var data = [{
    "title": "abc",
    "Upstream": 50,
    "Downstream": 15
  },
  {
    "title": "xyz",
    "Upstream": 107,
    "Downstream": 12
  }
]
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["green", "red"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "title";
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
});

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.title;
}));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
})]);

// x-axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Y-axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Number of Regulated Genes");

// Bars
var title = svg.selectAll(".title")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.title) + ",0)";
  });

title.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ages;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

title.selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ages;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .classed('bar-label', true)
  .text(d => d.value)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name) + x1.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value) + 4;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'hanging')


// Legends which is in right side
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.bar-label {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```